# Problem installing PostgreSQL 12 on CentOS 8

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos8, postgresql-12

Installing PostgreSQL 12:

```
sudo dnf install @postgresql:12
```

Then, contrib package for additional features: `sudo dnf install postgresql-contrib`

Afterwards, when I try to initialize the PostgreSQL database:

```
sudo postgresql-setup initdb
```

I'm getting: `sudo: postgresql-setup: command not found`

Also, when I try to check the status:

```
 sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

Getting this error: `Unit postgresql.service could not be found.`

What I'm doing wrong? If this way of installing is wrong, is there another option to install postgresql on centos?

Comment: Did you follow all steps from https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/ for CentOS 8 ? Make sure to follow exact steps from this link.

Comment: You need to install postgresql-server

Answer (score 2):

You have only installed the PostgreSQL client application on your server. In order to install the server software, you need to install the `postgresql-server` package which will satisfy those package dependencies. Afterwards you can follow this documentation to continue provisioning, configuring, and maintaining your new database.

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

This gist of which, as you originally mentioned, is simply:

```
  postgresql-setup initdb
  systemctl enable postgresql.service --now
```